# Solo una sesión activa por usuario en Laravel Sentinel

Tags: php, laravel

¿Cómo podría limitar a que el usuario solo pueda tener una sesión iniciada en el sistema a la vez? 
Estoy utilizando el sistema de autenticación Sentinel. 
En el caso que intente iniciar sesión por segunda vez debería cerrar la anterior y si es posible que sea de diferente equipo.

Comment: No indicas con que versión de laravel trabajas pero puedes revisar esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#invalidating-sessions-on-other-devices

Comment: ¿lograste hallar la manera? Estoy en las mismas, quisiera limitar un usuario a 1 o a n sesiones activas por usuario. Trabajo con Laravel 5.8